# Python: how to simulate the roll of a dice 100 times

Tags: python-3.x

I want to write an program that simulates the roll of a dice 100 times, but how do i have to do that?
This is the code:

```
import random

def roll() :
print('The computer will now simulate the roll of a dice 100 times')
number = random.randint(1,6)

print([number])


roll()
```

Comment: indent your code properly and call `roll()` a hundred times, something like `for i in xrange(100): roll()`

Comment: What output do you expect?  A list of the 100 rolls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creates a list of 100 rolls:

```
import random

print([random.randint(1,6) for _ in xrange(100)])
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of dansalmo seems good, but if you're using Numpy

You just need to use `numpy.random.randint(1,6,100)` as that would be much more efficient and will also use **discrete uniform distribution** to take out the values